# Vue2 Component not rendering when data is updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a case where a Vue 2 component isn't rendering when I update its data:

```
Vue.component('framer-deal', {
  data: function(name,src) {
      return {
         name : "Image1",
         src : "https://via.placeholder.com/250"
      }
  },
  created: function () {
    eventHub.$on('clickedImage', this.updateimage)
  },
  methods:{
        updateimage : function(imgsrc) {
           this.src = imgsrc;
           this.name = imgsrc;
            console.log("thumbnail", this.$data.name)
        }
     },
  template: '<div><h3>Hello {{name}} {{src}}</h3><img v-bind:src="this.src" /></div>'
})
```

JS Bin example: https://jsbin.com/wokiqozipa/edit?js,output

(I'm using an eventhub to trigger a method on the component, but this shouldn't be why the rendering is not triggered.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you have 2 Vue instances in your example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        json: mydata
    },
    methods: {
      open: function(e){
        
        imageframe = e.target.src;
        eventHub.$emit('clickedImage', imageframe)
    }
  }
});

new Vue({ el: '#frame' }) // remove this to make it work
```

Remove `new Vue({ el: '#frame' })` to make it work...

Also do not use `this` in the template.

Change

`<div><h3>Hello {{name}} {{src}}</h3><img v-bind:src="this.src" /></div>`

to

`<div><h3>Hello {{name}} {{src}}</h3><img v-bind:src="src" /></div>`

Comment: Thanks, nice catch!